# Copy or Move Sqlite Local Database from Output Directory to new Folder Directory

Tags: c#, sqlite, directory

This is a c# programming using visual studio 2015, I have a question this is quite challenging for me. I have an application that create one instance as my installer for the users, then Every instance installed in their PC a local database is attached to that output directory. However I find it difficult to move that database to specific new Directory I created. The reason why I need to move the database its because for every user, there should only one database that should be set if the application is run for the first time. And if there's a new version that database should not be affected unless i set it again differently.
Hope anyone would be able to help me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to move the database file (presumably a `.db`) from one directory to the other? If so then

```
File.Copy(@"someDirectory\someFile.txt", @"otherDirectory\someFile.txt");
```

should work just fine.